# Clear cell content based on another cell calculation

Tags: vba, excel

this is an Excel/VBA question:

I have a cell A1 in sheet2 linked cell `A1` in `sheet1` (simply `A1='sheet1'!A1`). `A1` in `sheet1` is a data validation drop down menu.

I want to clear the content of `A2` in `sheet2` every time the content of `A1` in sheet2 changes/is updated. That is every time the value of `A1` in `sheet1` is changed using the drop down menu.

I tried using a `Worksheet_Change` event macro (*which I do not fully understand*) but it won't work with a cell that updates from a calculation. It also doesn't work if triggered from a cell from another worksheet (I tried linking it to cell `A1` on `sheet1` in this case).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Range("A2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Can you think of a simple solution to clear the content of cell `A2` in `sheet2` when `A1` in `sheet2` updates?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me...

This code goes in the Sheet code area of Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then _
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Still best to disable events in case there is further code on Sheet2 :)