# clearing contents based on a differnt cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to clear content of a certain cell depending on a value in another cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Range("AL4").Value = 1 Then
        Range("AK15").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
     If Range("AL4").Value = 2 Then
        Range("AK15").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This somehow is not working, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear cell content based on another cell calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995119/clear-cell-content-based-on-another-cell-calculation)

Comment: You should always avoid using .Select statements, are you trying to loop through a column? Is "AL4" and "AK15" dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

- `Worksheet_Change2` is the name of your code, which will not work the same as `Worksheet_Change`
- You don't use the `Target` to define the range that you want to check for changes.
  Change `If Range("AL4").Value = 1` to:

  ```
  If not Intersect(Target, Range("AL4")) Is Nothing Then 
     If Range("AL4").Value = 1 or Range("AL4").Value = 2 Then
         Range("AK15") = ""
     End If
  End if
  ```

Using this checking for changes, you can implement it within your already existing `Worksheet_Change` module, and only fire this one when the value of cell AL4 has changed.

If you want to read up on the worksheet change event, I suggest reading this page from [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

- There is a 2 in the method name that shouldn't be there. The name is significant in this case
- You are missing two End Ifs
- To avoid cascading events you need to disable events before changing values
- Don't use Select. It works but it will give you trouble

This sums up to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("AL4").Value = 1 Then
            Range("AK15").ClearContents
    End If
    If Range("AL4").Value = 2 Then
            Range("AK15").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you! I added the "2"because I already have a sub Worksheet Change and it does not allow me to have the same name.. what can I do? Do I have to make a one big sub for all my worksheet changes?

Comment: Create small methods `Sub ClearSomething()` doing the separate tasks. Then call these from the _Change method

Answer (score 0):

Ella -

The below should solve what your trying to achieve

```
If Range("AL4").Value = 1 Or 2 Then
    Range("AK15") = ""
End If
```

or

```
If Range("AL4").Value = 1 Or 2 Then
    Range("AK15").ClearContents
End If
```

You want to try and not use the SELECT feature as it will slow down processing greatly